# GitLab Repository Mirroring - Push Only, No Pull Option

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket, pull

I'm trying to mirror a BitBucket repository on our internally-hosted GitLab server however, when I come to the Mirroring options in GitLab, only "Push" is available.

What determines whether "Pull" is available as a mirroring option?

I'm running GitLab 12.1.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Pulling from a remote repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html#pulling-from-a-remote-repository-starter) is only available in GitLab Starter (self-managed) and Bronze (GitLab.com) and higher tiers. The Core/FOSS version does not have this feature.

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks. I'm certain I saw it available as an option earlier in the day. Maybe I was mistaken. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Please consider accepting my answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers